# Output multiple duplicate keys instead of array in Jolt spec

Tags: json, jolt

I need to rearrange incoming structure and output multiple duplicate keys with different values, but jolt spec is giving me array instead of keys

Input data:

```
{
"TestData": {
    "data": {
        "Products": [
            {
                "Name": {
                    "key": "Name__c",
                    "value": "Example1"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": {
                    "key": "Name__c",
                    "value": "Example2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Desired output:

```
{
"TestData": {
    "data": {
        "Name__c": "Example1",
        "Name__c": "Example2"
    }
}
```

}

When i'm using following spec:

```
[
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
        "*": {
            "data": {
                "Products": {
                    "*": {
                        "Name": {
                            "value": "TestData.data.@(1,key)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

Its giving me

```
{
"TestData": {
    "data": {
        "Name__c": [
            "Example1",
            "Example2"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know how to handle this in Jolt?
Thanks

Comment: In your desired output, there is an duplicate key `Name__c`. JSON does not allow duplicate key.

Comment: @Jagadesh thank you, brief overview regarding the issue: desired output needs to be processed to ApiGee proxy which uses JSONThreatProtection policy at the preflow proxy..but unfortunately that specific policy does not validate duplicate json keys.